# Importing excel sheets to database not working

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am rewriting my database code to import to the new backend of my split database which when I run the code works. but nothing is showing up as new import. I am wondering am I missing something from my code. It runs fine I am not receiving any errors at all but none of the excel sheets are importing when I run the function below.  Any easier way would also be great too. In the end once the tables are created I want the imports to be linked back to the front end database.

```
Private Function ImportBackend()
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean, blnEXCEL As Boolean, blnReadOnly As Boolean
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim objExcel As Object, objWorkbook As Object
Dim colWorksheets As Collection
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim strPassword As String
Dim db As DAO.Database

Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase    ("C:\Users\albroady\Documents\Database\MasterDataCommit1_2018-12-18_be.accdb")
 ' Establish an EXCEL application object
On Error Resume Next
Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
 If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  'Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  'blnEXCEL = True
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
' has field names
 blnHasFieldNames = True

 ' Replace C:\Filename.xls with the actual path and filename
  strPathFile = "C:\Users\albroady\Documents\Master\Green.xlsx"

 ' Replace passwordtext with the real password;
  'if there is no password, replace it with vbNullString constant
 ' (e.g., strPassword = vbNullString)
strPassword = "vbNullString"

blnReadOnly = True ' open EXCEL file in read-only mode

' Open the EXCEL file and read the worksheet names into a collection
Set colWorksheets = New Collection
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPathFile, , blnReadOnly, , _
  strPassword)
For lngCount = 1 To objWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
  colWorksheets.Add objWorkbook.Worksheets(lngCount).Name
Next lngCount

' Close the EXCEL file without saving the file, and clean up the EXCEL objects
objWorkbook.Close False
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
If blnEXCEL = True Then objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing

'Import the data from each worksheet into a separate table
 For lngCount = colWorksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
        "tbl_Update" & colWorksheets(lngCount), strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames, _
        colWorksheets(lngCount) & "$"
Next lngCount
 ' Delete the collection
  Set colWorksheets = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing


  ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
  ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
  ' Kill strPathFile
```

Comment: One approach is to import to the frontend and then run a SELECT INTO action to create table in backend. Otherwise, won't be able to use TransferSpreadsheet. Regardless, will need code to establish link.

Comment: Don't put the vbNullString constant within quote marks.

Comment: Is this a one-time effort just to get db established? Run code in the backend. Then manually set links in frontend.

Comment: Hello this is a database that should be constantly updated.

Comment: I think my first comment still applies. Really should import records into existing tables.

Comment: I figured it out you actually can modify the properties of the query in the Design view and changing the destination from Current to the pathway of the backend database

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out you actually can modify the properties of the query in the Design view and changing the destination from Current to the pathway of the backend database